# Why does benzene have a D6h point group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

I understand the fact that the molecule has a principal axis of rotation of C6 however when following the point gorup flow chart why is the answer to the second question NO when it contains two C3 axis? Hence the answer should be a YES right? (I understand the molecule has C2 axis as well) [image: Point group flow chart]

Comment: Only different axes count.

Comment: Also, you chart seems to miss the groups $T,\;T_h,\;O,\;\text{ and }I$.

Comment: As @IvanNeretin stated - There's rather 1 C6 axis, than 2 C3 axis

Answer (score 2):

> Does it have two or more $C_2$ axes with $n>2$?

This question is asking if there is more than one $C_{n>2}$ **axis** not if there is more than one $C_{n>2}$ symmetry operation.

Yes, benzene has some $C_3$ operations. However, as pointed out in the comments, the $C_3$ axis lies along the $C_6$ axis - both run through the center of the ring perpendicular to the plane of the molecule. This axis is also a $C_2$ axis. There is only **one** $C_{n>2}$ axis - it just happens to be both a $C_6$ and a $C_2$ axis. All other rotation axes in benzene are $C_2$.

[image]

Comment: While reading https://www.nature.com/articles/srep25670 I double checked the definition of $D_{6h}$ and this question came up in a search. While it's not related to benzene *per se* the following question in Math SE is about graphene-like [xene materials](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/123524/16035) and probably requires an understanding of symmetries to address. Any thoughts or recommendations? [Determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619)